# How can I Ensure a User can only Vote Once on my ReactJS App Without any User Authentication?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, local-storage, ip, voting

I am creating a web app for a DJ where users can open up the site by QR code and request songs. Another section displays the current lineup, with up and downvoting capabilities. I current have it set so when the player votes, they can only upvote or downvote while on the page, and this is reflected in my database. I am using firebase as my database.

The issue is when the user refreshes the page, if the request is still there, they can vote again in any way as the previous is not stored through sessions based on device ID, or maybe IP address.

My ideas to go about this is:

1. Track user IP address using Axios as I found online, save the IP-Address as the key along with their vote as the value in my database. If they don't leave the area before the request is played, there shouldn't be an issue.
   Issues if the users IP address changes:

- Can't track the vote anymore and they can vote again.
- Aother user who may be assigned that previous IP address now has a vote they didn't assign.

2. Use local storage to hold a value for the vote based on the request ID, if they have the website open and the request is removed I could run code to clear the local storage of this information in the onUpdate handler I have on for the database reference. Not sure if this is great either because I'm not sure how well this works on mobile as that will be the target audience.

Is there a proper way that other websites go about this tack without user authentication?

Comment: Its kind of impossible without authentication even if you use multiple factors like IP, cookies, browser info, etc. Any of those can be changed. Even if you add authentication, there's always risk of users creating multiple accounts.

Comment: @Dharmaraj I understand it's not 100% certain, I'm more or less looking for a reasonable feasible solution. I should've clarified in the question header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any effective solution for this. Storing something in localhost or cookies will not work as that can be deleted by user to vote again.

As Frank answered, Anonymous authentication might be the way to go its much easier to clear auth state in webs than in native application.
As I commented earlier, even if you decide to use a authentication service, users may still create multiple accounts unless you have a list of guests beforehand and restrict voting to those accounts similar to what universities  do for online tests. 
IP based filters may not work in your use case as there may be many users in the same network.

The best you can do is to make it harder for the end user to figure out the factor that you use to distinguish the users (using multiple factors like IP, browser, some fingerprint, etc). You can also use a managed service like [Fingerprint](https://fingerprint.com/) (has an open source version) for that.

This still however doesn't restrict users from using multiple devices now however it might help reduce number of duplicate votes. Now that you have multiple other factors in place, you can also restrict votes to the location of event (or even better, the local network at that place) only so users cannot simply share the link somewhere else for some bots to cast votes.

Comment: I appreciate it, yeah for now I'm using the local storage and IP address check, until I find a comfortable setup for this anonymous authentication  you guys mention. I'm not overly familar with how you would go about anonymous authentication when the user would refresh the page or delete history/cache and they would thus drop the authentication they had. I'm sure there's a way and I just don't know it. I'll check out that Fingerprint service though, thanks

Comment: @Kastor438 anonymous auth would be equivalent to storing something in local storage in this case. Also, you seem to be looking for a general solution. Any reason why you tagged your question with Firebase? Are you looking for a solution with Firebase only>?

Comment: Well firebase is the database I am using holding song requests, votes, stats etc. I just added it in case it made a difference in the topic. I went ahead and did local storage, works okay, but doing just local storage isn't too great. I tried to add the IP check, but my phone and laptop have the same public IP and I'm afraid in production this may be the issue for many users in one localized area. So that's no good either. @Dharmaraj

Comment: I found a fingerprint open source, as you mentioned, works perfect to my needs! Thanks @Dharmaraj

Answer (score 2):

The common approach I'd take for that is to sign the user in with [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth), which gives them a unique UID that persists when they reload the page without requiring them to enter any credentials. So if you then associate the vote with that UID, each user can only vote once.

Comment: So you're saying basically sign them up through firebase authentication with seemingly random login information, but unique, and maybe persist that infomation in their local storage? This way it remains there to check on each reload? if they we're to clear this information, sure they could vote again but it wouldn't be the end of the world for the average user. Does this make a reasobale approach? How would you go about holding this information through sessions?

Comment: Firebase already persists the authentication information, so you don't need to do that yourself. --- And yes, if they clear that info they could vote again. If you want to prevent that, you have to have the users identify themselves.

Comment: Nice approach Frank!